# Why "ip route get" report "Network is unreachable" while I can stil receive packets?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a kubernetes cluster(more specifily, a kubeedge cluster), this cluster have 3 nodes:

- shanghai: 10.22.48.21
- node1: 10.22.48.12
- edge1: 10.22.48.13

also a client machine: 10.40.20.181.

I used flannel in this cluster and also fabedge to take care of traffic between cloud sides and edge side.

Here is the problem I encountered:

I execute "ip r get 10.233.66.34 from 10.22.48.12" on shanghai node and get error "
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable"(10.233.66.34 is an pod IP assigned to pod on edge1 node1)

My problem is: why did this error happen?

Here is the route table on shanghai node:

```
[root@shanghai ~]# ip r show table main
default via 10.22.48.254 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.22.48.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.22.48.21 metric 100 
10.233.64.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.233.64.1 
10.233.65.0/24 via 10.233.65.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.233.68.0/24 via 10.233.68.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
169.254.169.254 via 10.22.48.11 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
[root@shanghai ~]# ip r show table 220
10.233.66.0/24 via 10.233.65.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.233.67.0/24 via 10.233.65.0 dev flannel.1 onlink
```

Another problem bothered me is although shanghai node report this error, I can still found packets from 10.40.20.181 to 10.233.66.34, on node1 which served as router, how was that even possible?

```
05:31:12.699648 flannel.1 In  IP 10.40.20.181.54580 > 10.233.66.34.80: Flags [S], seq 241297879, win 64240, options [mss 1276,sackOK,TS val 1131723081 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,unknown-145 0x1815090500080a2864fdcc8c0bbd], length 0
05:31:12.700137 eth0  In  IP 10.233.66.34.80 > 10.22.48.12.11792: Flags [S.], seq 2966150963, ack 241297880, win 64704, options [mss 1360,sackOK,TS val 2311535627 ecr 1131723081,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:31:12.700160 eth0  Out IP 10.233.66.34.80 > 10.40.20.181.54580: Flags [S.], seq 2966150963, ack 241297880, win 64704, options [mss 1360,sackOK,TS val 2311535627 ecr 1131723081,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:31:13.699355 flannel.1 In  IP 10.40.20.181.54580 > 10.233.66.34.80: Flags [S], seq 241297879, win 64240, options [mss 1276,sackOK,TS val 1131724081 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,unknown-145 0x1815090500080a2864fdcc8c0bbd], length 0
05:31:13.699707 eth0  In  IP 10.233.66.34.80 > 10.22.48.12.11792: Flags [S.], seq 2966150963, ack 241297880, win 64704, options [mss 1360,sackOK,TS val 2311536626 ecr 1131723081,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:31:13.699720 eth0  Out IP 10.233.66.34.80 > 10.40.20.181.54580: Flags [S.], seq 2966150963, ack 241297880, win 64704, options [mss 1360,sackOK,TS val 2311536626 ecr 1131723081,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Comment: cross-posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/1136793/why-ip-route-get-report-network-is-unreachable-while-i-still-can-receive-pac